# Encapsulated css with Angular 7 + Webpack 4

Tags: angular, angular7, webpack-4, angular-hybrid

I have a [hybrid](https://github.com/ui-router/angular-hybrid) environment with both Angular 1.x and Angular 7 routes.
The Angular 1.x routes are using old bootstrap 3, while the Angular 7 should use bootstrap 4.
I tried to encapsulate bootstrap 4 only for the Angular 7 routes by importing it

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

inside the component

```
styles: [`    
    @import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  `]
```

but I keep getting

> ERROR in Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
>       at normalizeBackSlashDirection (C:\Users...\RequestShortener.js:16:17)
>       at new RequestShortener (C:\Users...\RequestShortener.js:26:15)
>       at new Compiler (C:\Users\r...\Compiler.js:185:27)
>       at Compiler.createChildCompiler (C:\Users...\Compiler.js:508:25)
>       at Compilation.createChildCompiler (C:\Users...\Compilation.js:2494:24)
>       at Object.pitch (C:\Users...\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\loader.js:70:43)
>   The only option that worked was to directly import the css to the module by adding the following to the top of the component:

```
import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

but then bootstrap 4 overrides bootstrap 3 classes and breaks my Angular 1.x styling.

Helpppp

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use `styleUrls: [],` inside your component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss', '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'],
})
```

Comment: I get the same `Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined` error

Comment: @RonyFragin What is the value of `<base>` in index.html?

Comment: <base href="/">

Answer (score 0):

IMO you can not have both 3 & 4 without conflicts.

> I have a hybrid environment with both Angular 1.x and Angular 7 routes

why would you need this in the first place?

Comment: I'm working on a big app and gradually upgrading it to Angular 7. I want to override 3 with 4 only for the Angular 7 code.